# Handling ng-pattern behaviour inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have set an `ng-show` to fire when the user enters an invalid character according to the regex defined in the `ng-pattern`; it looks like this:

```
<form name = "itemForm">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <textarea name = "listItemsArea" cols="50" rows="2" class="form-control" ng-model="summaryTabModel.itemList" ng-pattern="/^[0-9,\b\s]+$/"></textarea>
                </div>
                <span ng-show="itemForm.listItemsArea.$error.pattern">Input not valid!</span>
            </form>
```

Is it possible to handle the error on the `ng-pattern` inside of the controller? If so what do I have to pass to it? For example could I refer to the pattern error something like:

```
$scope.$error.pattern
```

Thanks

Comment: I think `ng-pattern` is a core directive. So it's difficult to manipulate this in a controller. I suspect that this keeps a separation of duties as if you manipulate the `ng-pattern` in the controller, you end up with coupling between the controller and the directive. Alternative, you could create a custom directive with custom validators for your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of a way, <strike>but I don't think it's idiomatic.</strike>

[Check it...](http://jsfiddle.net/ngs3M/)

```
function formCtrl($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$watch("itemForm.listItemsArea.$error.pattern", function(newval, oldval) {
        $log.error("Whoops", newval, oldval);
    });
}
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the log.error is fired as soon as the page is loaded

Comment: @Katana24 How is that a problem? Just return from it if there's no error.

Comment: In that case just compare oldVal and newVal if there is any change then do the manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/lalom/1/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.$watch('itemForm.listItemsArea.$error.pattern' , function(value){
$scope.isError = value;

}
              );

});
```